# get undefined in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am starting my study on angular. I created my first plunker today and used angularjs 1.4 tempalate. But i am getting error `person is not defined`

What is wrong with my code

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
 var person = {
firstName: "Kiran",
lastName: "Nandedkar"
};
 $scope.name = 'World';

$scope.person = person;
});
```

Here is my [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/PQXRqO0hY3JGEIEcauVE?p=preview)

**Update**
  Not sure why question is downvoted. I was trying in chrome browser and it was not working. Now i tried on mozilla and its working.

Comment: Nothing is wrong actually, your plunker works perfectly fine.

Comment: I can't see that error anywhere in your Plunkr

Comment: your plunker is working fine !! Do you please regenerate error in your plunker ?

Comment: You set `name = 'World'` and it's display what you want. What's the error? @@

Comment: @Boaz $scope is injected by default ;)

Comment: Please check the code snippet . Its working fine

Comment: It's working on chrome as well. If you have no other issues you can remove your question as it leads to nowhere.

Comment: OP: Plunkr immediately executes code as you type. It's entirely possible that `person` *wasn't* defined when you got that error but now it is so there is no issue.. Either clear your console, or tell Plunkr not to automatically execute the code, but there is no problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine. Your code is absolutely correct.

```
<p>Hello {{person.firstName}}!</p>
```

Test this code on html page

Answer (score 0):

Its working absolutely fine

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
   var person = {
    firstName: "Kiran",
    lastName: "Nandedkar"
  };
  $scope.name = 'World';
 
   $scope.person = person;
   
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">



  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
    <p>Hello {{person.firstName}} {{person.lastName}}!</p>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: if it's working fine then your answer is redaundent.

Comment: It wasnt displaying first name and last name on template. As he asked he is very new and started learning , I shown him How he can see these on templates.

Comment: You can mention that as a comment in the question.